# css dropdown div not appearing on hover

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I want the `.dropright`-div (containing text:"This is dropright" to appear on the right of `.main` div (containing text:"This is main text.") whenever I hover on the .main  Its not happening. What could be the reason.

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    /* [disabled]width: 100%; */
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.main {
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
    border: thin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropright {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
}
.main a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.main:hover .dropright {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <a href="http://www.hotmail.com">This is main text.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropright">This is dropright</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not how it works, the `.main a:hover .dropright` selector is not selecting any element. Read about selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: One thing you can do though, is to move `.dropright` inside of `<div class="main">`, and use the selector `.main:hover .dropright`.

Answer (score 2):

You Need to change this class. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t9j68eza/)

```
.main a:hover .dropright {
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

TO

```
.main:hover + .dropright {
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

Comment: I suggest updating this answer to explain the difference between descendant and adjacent sibling selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body {
     margin: 0px;
     height: 100%;
     /* [disabled]width: 100%; */
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }

a {
 text-decoration: none; 
}
    .wrapper {
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 0;
     margin-left: auto;
     height: 100%;
     max-width: 960px;
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
     margin-right: auto;
     position: relative;
    }

    .main {
 height: auto;
 width: 50%;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
 border: thin solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
 display: inline-block;
    }

.dropright {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
 height: auto;
 width: 25%;
 display: none;
 /* [disabled]position: absolute; */
}

.main a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropdown-box:hover .dropright {
 display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="dropdown-box">
  <div class="main">
    <a href="http://www.hotmail.com">This is main text.</a>
    </div>
   <div class="dropright">This is dropright</div>
   </div>
</div>
    
    
    

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello sarika. Thats exactly what I wanted. But where have you defined the rules for the `.dropdown-box` ? And why have you made the .dropdown-box as the parent of all divs?

Comment: There is no sence in a:hover .droplight{display:inline-block;}
if you want to display inline-block .droplight it should be hover on its parent element

Comment: ok. so from what I understand is that u created the class dropdown-box only because you can define the hover rule on its child element which is : `.dropright` . Am I correct?

Comment: Ya, It define as per rule of css hover

Comment: So then Sarika, can you please explain why is it when I define `.main:hover .dropright {display: inline-block;}` This doesnt work? After all `.main` is also a parent of `dropright` ?

Comment: It is Working :  HTML Code: <div class="main">
     <a href="http://www.hotmail.com">This is main text.</a>
     <div class="dropright">This is dropright</div>
   </div>
   </div> CSS: .main:hover .dropright {
  display: inline-block;  
}

Comment: Its not working Sarika. Please see above. I have updated the code.

Comment: See My other answer : Check This Code for Hover on main class:

Comment: Ok thanks. I got it now. The `.dropright` needs to be the child of `.main` in html code.

Answer (score 0):

Check This Code for Hover on main class:

```css
 
html,body {
      margin: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      /* [disabled]width: 100%; */
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    }

a {
  text-decoration: none;  
}
    .wrapper {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-left: auto;
      height: 100%;
      max-width: 960px;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
      margin-right: auto;
      position: relative;
    }

    .main {
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204,1);
  border: thin solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
  display: inline-block;
    }

.dropright {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
  height: auto;
  width: 25%;
  display: none;
  /* [disabled]position: absolute; */
}

.main a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main:hover .dropright {
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
<div class="wrapper">


  <div class="main">
    <a href="http://www.hotmail.com">This is main text.</a>
    
   <div class="dropright">This is dropright</div>
   </div>
</div>
    
    
    

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to do something that requires jQuery or Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('#right').addClass('dropright');
    });
});
```

Comment: You would then write an identical function for mouseleave. I can write a fully working version tomorrow when I wake up. I'm on mobile now.

Comment: You would also remove the class of topright from your html div(but keep it in your css file)and instead give it the id of "right", as well as remove the display none from top rights css if you want to try the jquery yourself before I get to it, or someone else steals my thunder.

Comment: Sounds like your starting to attempt things that plain old css can't do anymore for you. Oh the joyous journey of javascript that awaits.

Comment: I love the down vote by some hater who is probably mad that my answer is the right one.

Comment: Thanks. Earlier was better. Had some guy write an epic javascript function for me, then the bad apples came out.